# $f\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 $ be defined by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=....$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $f\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 $ be defined by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2+x_3,x_3+x_1,x_1+x_2).$ Then the first derivative of $f$ is :
>   1.not invertible anywhere
>   2.invertible only at the origin
>   3.invertible everywhere except at the origin
>   4.invertible everywhere.

My problem is I do not know how to calculate the derivative of $f$. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: the derivative is a linear transformation $f':\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that its matrix is

$$[f']=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3}
\end{array} \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

The question is most likely looking for the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant):

$$J=f'(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial{x_1}} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial{x_2}} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial{x_3}}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial{x_1}} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial{x_2}} &\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial{x_1}}\\\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial{x_1}} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial{x_2}} &\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial{x_3}}\end{bmatrix}$$

This seems like a lot of work, but since this is a linear transformation, the Jacobian will be identical to the transformation matrix itself.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f$ will be a three-by-three matrix, where the mnth entry is $\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}$.

This means row 1 column 1 entry will be 0, row 1 column 2 will be 1. row 1 column 3 entry will be 1 etc.